# Why Angularjs Directive Template is not rendering?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have tried a basic angularjs app. My controller is working ok but template in directive doesn't seems to work, please suggest the solution.

Below is my code

index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="DataApp1">
    <head>

        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div data-ng-controller="DataController1">     
            <data-directive> </data-directive>
         </div>

        <script src="Scripts/App.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

app.js

```
 /// <reference path="angular.js" />

var myapp = angular.module("DataApp1", []);

myapp.controller("DataController1", function ($scope) {

});

myapp.directive("dataDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h2>Hi</h2>'
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on your naming convention,
Any text accompanied by `data-` is considered without it in angularjs,

Example: `data-ng-model, data-ng-bind`

Name your directive like this `directive` and call it with or without using `data-`, both are same

Then it works!

[Working Plunker with your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/DlLNOIUDfhcsZo3V07z3?p=preview)

See docs

[Directive Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: ok great, I knew it but made mistake  :) thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would refrain from using data- on your angular directives. It's really not needed.

Also, i would place the ng-app directive on your body tag, it increases the speed of your page load. Even if it is only slightly, every little bit counts when you get into enterprise level application development.

Comment: data- is optional , but is it really speedup my page load if I put ng-app directive to my body tag? how much faster? can you prove it by any example?

Comment: It's slightly faster as it reduces the size of your scope by not having to include the elements in the <head>. 

The only reason why you would want to declare ng-app on the html document is if you wanted to manipulate the title with it but then you can do the same thing by using $window.